# MMWormhole.framework crashes on iPhone 4/4s because of "wrong architecture". Works fine on 5/5s and 6

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, mmwormhole

I am bringing in the Wormhole library via Cocoapods. Everything works as expected on iPhone 5 and 6, but on 4s simulator it crashes at launch with the error below. Looks like all the architecture settings are correct and in-sync between app and used frameworks.

> Library not loaded: @rpath/MMWormhole.framework/MMWormhole
>   Referenced from:
>   /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F04DCEBB-2E34-49C7-9554-E6048D3349E2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BC69F59F-7896-44BE-A7E6-26B46A47E7FD/AppName.app/AppName
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F04DCEBB-2E34-49C7-9554-E6048D3349E2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BC69F59F-7896-44BE-A7E6-26B46A47E7FD/AppName.app/Frameworks/MMWormhole.framework/MMWormhole:
>   mach-o, but wrong architecture

Comment: You should probably reach out to the authors of the `MMWormhole` framework.

Comment: Submitted as an issue on their GitHub repo.